# saving large data set PCA on disk for later use with limited disc space

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pca

I have a very large data set (numpy array) that I do a PCA on for dimensionality reduction. The data set is called `train_data`. I use scikit-learn and do this like this

```
pca = PCA(n_components=1000, svd_solver='randomized')
pca.fit()
smaller_data = pca.transform(train_data)
```

I have a second data set called `test_data` that I want to use the same transformations on, like this:

```
smaller_test = pca.transform(test_data)
```

However, between these two steps I need to save the model to disk.

According to the scikit documentation, I can do this with pickle

```
pickle.dump(pca, open( "pca.p", "wb" ) )
```

but this pickle file is way too large for my limited disk space.

The reduced data set `smaller_data` is of acceptable size to be saved as a `.npy` file:

```
np.save('train_data_pca.npy', train_data)
```

How can I use this file to do a transform(test_data), or make the saved pca pickle smaller? Zipping using the gzip package is not enough, I tried that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a way, it is actually pretty easy after looking into the source code of the `transform` method in scikit.

I have to save the components means

```
means = pca.means_   #put this into a .npy file
```

and then it is just matrix multiplication:

```
from sklearn.utils.extmath import fast_dot
td = test_data - means
tdd = fast_dot(td, pca.components_.T)
```

yields the same as

```
pca.transform(test_data)
```